# .NET 7: Conditional Json serialization/deserialization

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization

I'm working on a .NET 7 api and I'm having a problem regarding Id field of the DTO object.

This is my UserDTO (used to return users in get as well as to post/put a user):

```
public class UserDTO
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string? FirstName { get; set; }
  public string? LastName { get; set; }
  public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
  public List<RoleDTO> Roles { get; set; } = new List<RoleDTO>();

  public bool ShouldSerializeId()
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

UsersController Post:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("users")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUserAsync(UserDTO u)
{
    ...
}
```

Get:

```
[HttpGet("user/{userId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserByIdAsync(string userId)
{
    var u = await _usersApplication.GetByIdAsync(userId);
    var user = _mapper.Map<UserDTO>(u);
    return Ok(user);
}
```

My problem is leaving the class like that, this next is the json presented by swagger as a Post request:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "firstName": "string",
  "lastName": "string",
  "status": true,
  "roles": [
    {
      "roleName": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

And, of course, I don't want "Id" to be present in the request as it is, obviously, auto-generated.

If I use the [JsonIgnore] attribute it works, but then the "Id" won't be presented in Get, where it is obviously needed.

What I need is a conditional serializer/deserializer.

I tried the "ShouldSerializeId" approach, but as I've read it does not work any more in .Net 7, as this version of .Net comes with a different Json serializer that does not support it.

How can I do a conditional serialization?

Comment: You need a `CreateUserDTO`.

Comment: Simple answer @CodeCaster. Thanks, and write it as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer - use different DTOs to create and return data:

```cs
public class CreateUserDTO
{
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string? FirstName { get; set; }
  public string? LastName { get; set; }
  public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
  public List<RoleDTO> Roles { get; set; } = new List<RoleDTO>();
}
```

Optionally you can share the base set of properties between `UserDTO` and `CreateUserDTO` via inheritance.

For serialization part (if you really need, though in this particular case it is an overkill) you can leverage [contract customization support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#contract-customization) added in .NET 7 to System.Text.Json:

```cs
class TestSe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public bool ShouldSerializeId { get; set; } = true;
}

void SetShouldSerialize(JsonTypeInfo info)
{
    if (info.Type == typeof(TestSe))
    {
        // NB: this uses JSON property name, not a class member name
        var jsonPropertyInfo = info.Properties.Single(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name == "Id");
        jsonPropertyInfo.ShouldSerialize = static (obj, val) => ((TestSe)obj).ShouldSerializeId;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var testSe = new TestSe
{
    Data = "data"
};
var opts = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers =
        {
            SetShouldSerialize
        }
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(testSe, opts)); // {"Id":0,"Data":"data"}
testSe.ShouldSerializeId = false;
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(testSe, opts)); // {"Data":"data"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to show Id property at all , the only way is  to separate your DTO into two

```
public class UserDTO:UserDtoBase
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserDTOBase
{
   public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string? FirstName { get; set; }
  public string? LastName { get; set; }
  public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
  public List<RoleDTO> Roles { get; set; } = new List<RoleDTO>();

}
```

and use without Id for post

Using JsonIgnore or the custom serializer is the same as just assign Id = null inside of the POST action since new Dto will be created, just Id will not be assigned and will be null by default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [JsonIgnore] decorator and Newtonsoft.NET JSONConverter?

```
public class UserDTO
{
  [JsonIgnore]
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string? FirstName { get; set; }
  public string? LastName { get; set; }
  public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
  public List<RoleDTO> Roles { get; set; } = new List<RoleDTO>();

  public bool ShouldSerializeId()
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Separate your object-structure into two objects- one model you'll save in your database (The returned object might be a DTO as well if you want to add data eg. "Time requested) and one for creating new Users.

```
public class User //This is the one you'll have in your database
{
  [Key]
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string? FirstName { get; set; }
  public string? LastName { get; set; }
  public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
  public List<RoleDTO> Roles { get; set; } = new List<RoleDTO>();
}

public class NewUserRequest //This is the one you'll send to your endpoint
{
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string? FirstName { get; set; }
  public string? LastName { get; set; }
  public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
  public List<RoleDTO> Roles { get; set; } = new List<RoleDTO>();
}
```

Comment: Why `[Key]`? I highly doubt that OP uses DTO as entities.

Comment: That's if they were using the User-model as entites. If they don't you're absolutely right and it shouldn't be there!

Comment: Based on the provided code - OP does not.